# How to replace a child frame in a QWidget class with another child frame belonging to another QWidget class dynamically

Tags: qt, qt4.8

I have one QWidget class having 2 child QFrames.
There is another QWidget class (in same project) containing multiple child frames.

I want to dynamically replace a child frame of my first class with a particular frame of second class.

Is there any possible way to copy the frames?